# Match Cells Value On Excel Vba Macro

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

How do I match cells value from another sheet? And if there is a match can I export value on specific cells?

Comment: Have you heard about the INDEX(MATCH) function? Is that you are after?

Comment: But can I do it automatic in vba?

Comment: If you parse the function properly, then yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a generic simple example
Say we want to search a worksheet called *"pirate island"* for a cell containing the text *"hidden treasure"*, If we find a match, we want the contents of the cell to the right of the cell we found.

Here is some code:

```
Sub MatchGame()
    Dim v As Variant, r As Range, rp As Range
    v = Range("A1").Value
    Set rp = Sheets("pirate island").Cells
    Set r = rp.Find(what:=v, After:=rp(1))
    
    If r Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "no treasure"
    Else
        MsgBox r.Offset(0, 1).Value
    End If
End Sub
```

We just put *"hidden treasure"* in cell **A1** of our main sheet and run the macro.

Comment: Hi but what if we want to do use the last row in v = Range("A1").Value? Thanks for help, thank you!